# How pass an object in parameter of another class in LS2J?

Tags: java, lotus-domino, ls2j

I am trying to pass an object of a java class (a bean) to another class with LS2J.

The problem is that an error is returned :

> LS2J Error: Threw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.pasquier.DTO.WS.LogWSDTO

I don't know why ?

I have a class bean normally with getter and setter.
I want to pass an instance of this class in another.

My class in Lotus LS2J :

```
Class LogWebService
    sessionJava As JAVASESSION      
    classJava As JAVACLASS
    objectJava As JAVAOBJECT        
    methodJava As JAVAMETHOD

    Public Sub New()
        Set sessionJava = New JAVASESSION
        Set classJava = sessionJava.GetClass("com.pasquier.launcher/LogWebService")
        Set objectJava = classJava.CreateObject     
    End Sub 

    Public Sub setLog(logDTO As LogWSDTO)
        Set methodJava = classJava.GetMethod("setLog","(Lcom/pasquier/DTO/WS/LogWSDTO;)V")      
             objectJava.setLog(logDTO)      
    End Sub 

End Class
```

It is the method setLog which crashes

I call it in the code :

```
Class LogGetAllDocumentsDAO

    Private ilog As LogWebService 
    Private logDTO As LogWSDTO
    Private docDTO As LogGetAllDocumentsDTO

    Public Sub New(logWSparam As LogWSDTO, docDTOparam As LogGetAllDocumentsDTO)
        Set Me.logDTO = logWSparam
        Set Me.docDTO = docDTOparam     
    End Sub 


    Public Sub appelLog()           
        Set ilog = New LogWebService()

        ' error: LS2J Error: Threw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pasquier.DTO.WS.LogWSDTO
        Call ilog.setLog(logDTO)


    End Sub
```

---

an idea ?

i have a class LogDTO in the same library than LogWebService.

```
Class LogWSDTO
sessionJava As JAVASESSION      
classJava As JAVACLASS
objectJava As JAVAOBJECT        
methodJava As JAVAMETHOD


Public Sub New()
    Set sessionJava = New JAVASESSION
    Set classJava = sessionJava.GetClass("com.pasquier.DTO.WS/LogWSDTO")
    Set objectJava = classJava.CreateObject     
End Sub
```

---

if i understand i can't pass logDTO with :

```
Set Me.logDTO = logWSparam
```

is it that ? But how i do then ??

---

well i try but it doesn't work.

I add a getObjet method in LS2J (not in java only on lotus)

```
Class LogWSDTO
sessionJava As JAVASESSION      
classJava As JAVACLASS
objectJava As JAVAOBJECT        
methodJava As JAVAMETHOD


Public Sub New()
    Set sessionJava = New JAVASESSION
    Set classJava = sessionJava.GetClass("com.pasquier.DTO.WS/LogWSDTO")
    Set objectJava = classJava.CreateObject     
End Sub


Public Function getJavaObject()
    Set getJavaObject = objectJava      
End Function
```

---

i try to call this in my prog :

```
Class LogGetAllDocumentsDAO

Private ilog As LogWebService 
Private logDTO As LogWSDTO
Private docDTO As LogGetAllDocumentsDTO

Public Sub New(logWSparam As LogWSDTO, docDTOparam As LogGetAllDocumentsDTO)        
    Set Me.logDTO = logWSparam
    Set Me.docDTO = docDTOparam     
End Sub 


Public Sub appelLog()           
    Call ajouterParam()         
    Set ilog = New LogWebService()      

    Call ilog.setLog(logDTO.getJavaObject())
End Sub
```

i can't save this change : it returns :

```
"type mismatch on : GETJAVAOBJECT"
```

---

---

so i try to add the method in LogWebService' s java class.
and i try in LS2J :

```
Public Function getJavaObject()         
    Set methodJava = classJava.GetMethod("getJavaObject","()Lcom/pasquier/DTO/WS/LogWSDTO;")        
    getJavaObject = objectJava.getJavaObject()  
End Function
```

---

i call with :

```
Public Sub appelLog()           
    Set ilog = New LogWebService()          
    Set logDTO = logDTO.getJavaObject
    Call ilog.setLog(logDTO)
```

and it doesn't works, same message, i cry !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objectJava.setLog(logDTO)` - logDTO has to be a Java object generated by LS2J. It won't work with a LotusScript class object.

Add a method getJavaObject() to your LotusScript class LogWSDTO which returns the LS2J Java object `objectJava`. Use it this way then:

```
objectJava.setLog(logDTO.getJavaObject())
```

*This is a working example:*

LotusScript agent:

```vb
Option Declare
UseLSX "*javacon"
Use "AandB"

Class LogWSDTO
    sessionJava As JAVASESSION      
    classJava As JAVACLASS
    objectJava As JAVAOBJECT        

    Public Sub New()
        Set sessionJava = New JAVASESSION
        Set classJava = sessionJava.GetClass("de.leonso.test/B")
        Set objectJava = classJava.CreateObject     
    End Sub

    Public Function getJavaObject()
        Set getJavaObject = objectJava      
    End Function
End Class

Sub Initialize
    Dim sessionJava As JAVASESSION      
    Dim classJavaA As JAVACLASS
    Dim objectJavaA As JAVAOBJECT        
    Dim lsB As LogWSDTO

    Set sessionJava = New JAVASESSION
    Set classJavaA = sessionJava.GetClass("de.leonso.test/A")
    Set objectJavaA = classJavaA.CreateObject     
    Set lsB = New LogWSDTO()

    print objectJavaA.a(lsB.getJavaObject())

End Sub
```

Java classes in Java ScriptLibrary "AandB":

```java
package de.leonso.test;

public class A {
    public String a(B b) {
        return b.b();
    }
}

package de.leonso.test;

public class B {
    public String b() {
         return ("hallo");
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a working example for your case. Go from there and adapt it to your solution.